# WebAPI [FromBody] as EF Model behaves like it is immutable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I have an WebAPI Controller that uses complex types from Entity Framework. When I receive the object I check to see if it exists. If it doesn't I'd like to create a new. Before I create a new I'd like to add a couple additional values to the object. If I add a break point and a watch I can see the value and it appears like it has changed. But the value doesn't make it to the database.

```
[Authorize(Roles ="customerprofileuser")]
[Route("api/CustomerProfile/Save")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveCustomerProfile([FromBody] MERP.Customer _input)
{
    Models.Message.Response _return = new Models.Message.Response();
    _return.Message = "Profile Saved!";
    _return.Now = DateTime.Now;

    try {
        ERPEntities ent = new ERPEntities();
        var cust = ent.Customers.AsNoTracking().Where(w => w.ID == _input.ID).FirstOrDefault();

        if (cust == null)
        {
            _input.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            _input.Alias = getCustomerNumberNext(_input.Type);
            _input.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;

            ent.Customers.Add(_input);
        }
        else
        {
            ent.Customers.Attach(_input);
            ent.Entry(_input).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        _return.ResponseObject = _input.ID.ToString();
        ent.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _return.Message = ex.Message;
        _return.Severity = 3;
    }
    return Ok(_return);
}
```

If I map the values to a new object like this, everything works as expected.

```
                var val = new Customer();
                val.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
                val.Active = _input.Active;
                val.Alias = getCustomerNumberNext(_input.Type);
                val.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;

                ent.Customers.Add(val);
```

I'd rather not map every single property to the new object property. Is there a way around this behavior?

Here's a sample of the auto-generated Customer class from my Entity Model.

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> Type { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> Salesman { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> SalesRegion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
    public string LinkedIn { get; set; }
    public string Facebook { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public string GoldmineFK { get; set; }
    public string SalesFK { get; set; }
    public string InventoryFK { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> Industry { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> Lead { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> Show { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> Territory { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the getCustomerNumberNext function

```
    private string getCustomerNumberNext(Guid? companyid)
    {
        ERPEntities ent = new ERPEntities();
        var _prefix = (from p in ent.CompanyLookups
                       where p.Type == "CustomerNumberPrefix"
                       select p.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

        var _number = (from p in ent.CompanyLookups
                       where p.Type == "CustomerNumberSequence"
                       select p.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

        var _newNumber = Convert.ToInt32(_number) + 1;

        try
        {
            var _update = (from p in ent.CompanyLookups
                           where p.Type == "CustomerNumberSequence"
                           select p).FirstOrDefault();
            _update.Value = _newNumber.ToString();
            ent.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { return ex.Message; }

        return _prefix + _number;
    }
```

**EDIT: The C# code works as expected. The issue was with the data round tripping from the client and incompleteness.**

Comment: You shouldn't prefix all your variables and parameters with underscores like this, common convention is to only do that for class level private variables.

Comment: Is `ErpEntities` your `DbContext`?

Comment: @Tim Yes, ERPEntitites is the DbContext.

Comment: I'm guessing the "AsNoTracking()" is the culprit. (2nd line in try block)  Can you try after removing the AsNoTracking? And is there any reason for not tracking the entities?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a typo in your question, which says "does make it to the database" but I believe you meant "does not make it to the database"

With that assumption I tried running similar code locally and was able to save the values as expected. The primary difference is that Alias is an integer in my code and I am assuming it is a complex class in your code. Here is the code that successfully saved the values to the database,

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/CustomerProfile/Save")]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveCustomerProfile([FromBody] Customer _input)
    {
        masterEntities masterEntities = new masterEntities();
        var cust = masterEntities.Customers.AsNoTracking().Where(w => w.ID == _input.ID).FirstOrDefault();

        if (cust == null)
        {
            _input.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            _input.Alias = 0;
            _input.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;

            masterEntities.Customers.Add(_input);
        }
        else
        {
            masterEntities.Customers.Attach(_input);
            masterEntities.Entry(_input).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }

        masterEntities.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Here is what the generated Customer class like,

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Alias { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Can you update your question with the Customer and Alias classes from your code and I can try reproducing that?

On a side note, I would suggest changing

```
var cust = ent.Customers.AsNoTracking().Where(w => w.ID == _input.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

to

```
var cust = ent.Customers.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(w => w.ID == _input.ID);
```

Comment: Added the samples.